# Issue in logstash conf file

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

I am facing issue in logstash conf file. Earlier it was working but now I have added one more condition in email alert block, now its getting crashed.

This is working part:

```
output {
elasticsearch { host => ["HOST1","HOST2"  ] port => "9200" protocol => "http" }
if [severity] in ['Erro', 'ERROR'] {
email {
        from => "testemail@testdomain.com"
        subject => "Attention | Email alert"
        to => "testemail@testdomain.com"
        via => "smtp"
        htmlbody => "<h2>Below log line has been reported</h2><br/><br/><div
        align='left'>%{message}</div>"
        options => [
               "smtpIporHost", "smtp.office365.com",
               "port", "587",
               "domain", "smtp.office365.com",
               "userName", "testemail@testdomain.com",
               "password", "testpwd",
               "authenticationType", "login",
               "starttls", "true"
       ]
}
}
stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Now Just added extra 'or' condition:

```
output {
    elasticsearch { host => ["HOST1","HOST2"  ] port => "9200" protocol => "http" }
    if [severity] in ['Erro', 'ERROR'] or [event] in "MssTooBusy" {
    email {
            from => "testemail@testdomain.com"
            subject => "Attention | Email alert"
            to => "testemail@testdomain.com"
            via => "smtp"
            htmlbody => "<h2>Below log line has been reported</h2><br/><br/><div
            align='left'>%{message}</div>"
            options => [
                   "smtpIporHost", "smtp.office365.com",
                   "port", "587",
                   "domain", "smtp.office365.com",
                   "userName", "testemail@testdomain.com",
                   "password", "testpwd",
                   "authenticationType", "login",
                   "starttls", "true"
           ]
    }
    }
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
    }
```

I am getting following error:

```
TypeError: can't convert nil into String
       include? at org/jruby/RubyString.java:4464
    output_func at (eval):1449
   outputworker at /opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-1.5.4-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:244
  start_outputs at /opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-1.5.4-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:166
```

Any pointers here will be greatly appreciated,

Thanks!

Comment: The problem is that you check a field that doesn't exist. That is why you get a `can't convert nil into String` error. Does your message contain an `[event]` field? Please double check your rubydebug output for valid fields.

Comment: It's there...Still problem persist..checked again

Comment: Try  [event] == "MssTooBusy" instead of  [event] in "MssTooBusy"

Comment: but what about If I want check in multiple values like 
`if [severity] in ['Erro', 'ERROR'] or [event] in [ 'MssTooBusy', 'MtaTooBusy']`